# Curl fails on TLS connection: sslv3 alert bad record mac

Tags: debian, curl, qemu, https

I'm running a fresh debian stretch installation in a VM using QEMU on a Ubuntu 14.04 host. When I use `curl` on any HTTPS resource like

```
curl -vL https://get.rvm.io/
```

I get this error:

```
*   Trying 2600:3c03::f03c:91ff:fedb:6957...
* TCP_NODELAY set
*   Trying 97.107.133.48...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to get.rvm.io (2600:3c03::f03c:91ff:fedb:6957) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* error:140943FC:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad record mac
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 1
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:140943FC:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad record mac
```

The same happens on any other HTTPS resource, not only on the RVM installer. What works:

- running `curl` on a HTTP resource,
- running `wget` on any resource,
- running anything on the host.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

## Update

Turns out I forgot to enable KVM when launching QEMU. Adding the `-enable-kvm` switch to my launch script resolved the problem.

However, I am still curious: How could these two issues be related?

Comment: Curl might depend on an instruction only functional with kvm, like aes